# What is the Michael Jackson DVD most like the King of Pop Collection CD?

Tags: michael-jackson

I want to give to my mom a Michael Jackson DVD on Mothers Day because she likes him very much, and wants to watch the movie clips of the music she likes. But searching [Mercado Livre](http://www.mercadolivre.com.br/) (a latin e-commerce site) returns many DVDs and I don't know which to choose. So I looked too at [Wikipedia's article on the videography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Jackson_videography), checking the track list of the discs. The best I found was 7 good tracks out of a total of 12... This is not enough to be worth buying. I don't want her watching the DVD only for half of the music-movies, and disliking the rest.

I wanted to find one DVD with tracklist very similar to "Michael Jackson - King of Pop - Brazillian Collection" (she likes this CD very much), that is:

1. Thriller
2. Don´t Stop 'Til You Get Enough
3. Billie Jean
4. Black Or White
5. Heal The World
6. Say Say Say
7. Beat It
8. Rock With You
9. Human Nature
10. Bad
11. You Are Not Alone
12. Will You Be There
13. The Way You Make Me Feel
14. Man In The Mirror

Bonus tracks from "Thriller 25th Anniversary":

15. Wanna Be Startin' Somethin' 2008 (Remix)
16. The Girl Is Mine 2008 (Remix)

Is there any DVD that is not listed on Wikipedia that might have these tracks on it?

Comment: How does this have 2 upvotes? It's literally a shopping question.

Comment: @DarrickHerwehe, shopping questions are not welcome here?